# imnoise gaussian and dct2() in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to do dicrete cosine transformation on black and white image and also I'm trying to do that transformation on the same image but with some noise on it. The problem is that imnoise adds "RGB noise" I would say, and because of that I cant do dct2() on my image. Easy example that I tried:

```
B = imnoise(A,'gaussian');
C = dct2(B);
```

How can I put noise on my image so it stays in grayscale mode?

Comment: I don't understand; using imnoise on a B & W image does not change the type of the data, it stays B & W.

Comment: It is B&W, but noise dots are colorized, I'm confused because of that

Comment: Mhh ok. Can you post your whole code with a sample image? You can give a link to the image and I or someone will post it.

Comment: Ok, here are pictures, first one is just the image I used, and the second one is with gaussian+salt&pepper noise added: http://s3.postimg.org/u050c0ub7/peng2.png   http://s8.postimg.org/4fvuwfpwl/peng_Noise.jpg

Comment: I hope you can see that noise dots are green, red and blue...I dont understand why. Code is:
B = imnoise(A,'gaussian');
C = imnoise(B,'salt & pepper');
dct2(C);